# Generate jsdoc documentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

I search to understand how operate jsdoc, the generator of javascript documentation. When I use it, I have always all my documentation files on index.js and never the navigation (in the documentation web site) in my files, classes or modules. Furthermore, I have also some tags which do not appear in the documentation. However, I use just the tags given by usejsdoc web site ([documentation of jsdoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)).

Version :

- Node.js : 6.9.1
- jsdoc   : 3.4.2

[image: View of generate documentation]

Server.js

```
"use strict";
/**
 * @module server
 * @file
 * The main file of this server. It create access routes. To use it, you can write on a terminal : $ node server.js                                 <br />
 * Turn in javascript strict mode.                                                                                                                  <br />
 * 
 * @version    1.0
 * @since      1.0
 *
 * @requires config
 * @requires express
 * @requires body-parser
 * @requires messenger.scenario
 * @requires messenger.routeMessenger
 */
const 
    // Official libraries
    /**
     * @access        public
     * @constant
     * @description   Use config file to param server.
     */
    config       =   require("config"),
    express      =   require('express'),
    bodyParser   =   require('body-parser'),
```

How do I generate the JSDoc documentation from my code?

Answer (score 8):

I add jsdocs to typical javascript project by adding a script to `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "docs": "./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js -c ./.jsdoc.conf.json"
}
```

and add a config file `.jsdoc.conf.json`

```
{
  "plugins": [],
  "recurseDepth": 10,
  "opts": {
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./docs/"
  },
  "source": {
    "include": ["src"],
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
    "excludePattern": "node_modules"
  },
  "sourceType": "module",
  "tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc", "closure"]
  },
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false
  }
}
```

this generates the docs in a folder `./docs` in the root of the project.

You can then generate project docs by running `npm run docs`.

You may also want to gitignore the generated docs. For full configuration options read http://usejsdoc.org/about-configuring-jsdoc.html