# How to run jsdoc on directory ignore .gitignore files

Tags: jsdoc

I can run jsdoc on a whole project with

```
$ jsdoc -r .
```

However this generates docs for js files inside `node_modules`. How can I tell jsdoc not run on files in `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a config file such as this one?

```
$ jsdoc.js -c ./.jsdoc.conf.json
```

**./.jsdoc.conf.json**

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": ["."],
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
    "excludePattern": "node_modules"
  }
}
```

Borrowed from [Generate jsdoc documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899849/generate-jsdoc-documentation) here on Stack.

Comment: Could you put `["./node_modules"]` in the `exclude` parameter and get the same result?

Comment: this doesn't work for some reason, it still goes into the directory.

Comment: Should be exclude, not excludePattern. ExcludePattern is used for regex, exclude is for explicitly named resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "source": {
    "include": ["."],
    "includePattern": ".(jsx|js|ts|tsx)$",
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "docs"
    ]
  }
}
```